# Tables not updating in MS Access through the visual basic login form?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

So I'm doing a car rental project for my I.T assignment. Everything is working fine except the data isn't updating through the program, i.e. if I add a new User through the program, it doesn't save into the Access Database, therefore I can't use it to log in. And if I manually enter a username and password directly into the table on the Access Database, it still does not allow me to log in with it.

I went on 'Data > Add New Data Source > Database > Dataset > CarRentalSystem1ConnectionString > Tables (selected) > Finish'. The database seems to be connected yet the information isn't updating from either side. Is it something to do with my coding?

Thanks for your help.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class LogIn

Dim con As New OleDbConnection
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    If ask() = True Then
        Main_Form.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password!", "Access Denied", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Cancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cancel.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub LogIn_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\Information Technology 11\Crown's Garage\FinalCarRentalSystem\CarRentalSystem1.mdb"
    con.Open()
    con.Close()
End Sub
Public Function ask()

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    con.Open()
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Admin", con)
    da.Fill(dt)

    For Each datarow In dt.Rows

        If UsernameTextBox.Text = datarow.item(1) And PasswordTextBox.Text = datarow(2) Then
            con.Close()
            Return True
        End If
    Next

    con.Close()
    Return False

End Function
End Class
```

Comment: 1) do not re-use one global connection  2) do not store passwords in plain text 3) you could use a SQL WHERE clause to at least select the users with matching names 4) the DB is probably part of the project and set to copy a new blank DB everytime you run. Change the Copy property (dozens upon dozens of this question here) 5) Turn on Option Strict. Always

Comment: @Plutonix What do you mean by not using one global connection? And for  the SQL part, the teacher says it has to be DB not SQL. Thanks again.

Comment: The Connection object should be created, used and disposed of each time; you have one global one for the whole form.  There is no need to get a DT of all the rows of all the users to test a login.  Use SQL to SELECT the users with the matching name to test just the PW. Or SELECT using the name and PW (hash!!!); if you get no rows, the login fails. The missing updates are likely the DB project property